# Pine Editor use plot() to create a constant line for the last X bars

Tags: pine-script

I'm writing you because I need your help to draw horizontal lines with the plot() fuction based on the last value of a serie.
I want to do the exact same thing as :

```
l = line.new(bar_index, serie, bar_index[10], serie)
line.delete(l[1])
l2 = line.new(bar_index, serie2, bar_index[10], serie2)
line.delete(l2[1])
```

But ! Then I need to fill background between l and l2 in specific condition. Unforutnetly, fill() is not compatible with line.new...

So, do you know a trick, to use plot(), with a constant serie egal to the last value I need to plot horizontally and a condition like : if the last 10 bars, color = something, else na...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can offset plots in the past by using `plot()`'s `offset` parameter:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
int i_ofset = input(10)
var float hi = na
var float lo = na
if rising(close, 5)
    hi := high
if falling(close, 5)
    lo := low
p_1 = plot(hi, "hi", color.orange, offset = - i_ofset)
p_2 = plot(lo, "lo", color.purple, offset = - i_ofset)
fill(p_1, p_2, hi < lo ? color.red : na, transp = 50)
```

[image]